# Selection menu at Login Screen for Language and Culture

Tags: login, language, localization

I have a web application which has

- An UI Language (All the normal translations)
- A Culture (Things like Number Formats and Date Formats)

The user should choose his Language and Culture at the Login Screen.

My question is:
Where to place the Culture Field (and how to name it)? In my example i placed it below the Languagefield. Or should i hide it an only make it accessible on demand? [image: Login Screen]

My fear is that the user gets confused if he has to choose both Language and Culture. But this option has to be available because for a example a user from Switzerland could choose to use the English language. But he also needs his Swiss Numberformat.

Comment: Are these 'culture' options going to be global - i.e. the same options available regardless of the language chosen, or are there specific culture options for each language? (Also, where did you get the term 'culture' from in this case? I've never heard of culture being used in this way before, the word has many other meanings, and associating it with Language is going to send very confusing messages to people - *'what is the culture of my language?'*

Comment: Yes they will be global. As I mentioned with the Switzerland  example. In Switzerland there are users that use the English language and there are users that use the German language. If a user in Switzerland now selects the English Language he normaly would get the English number formats. But he doesn't want the English number format - he wants the Swiss number format.

Comment: So you would still potentially want to offer the German Language option and the Swiss number format as a choice to the user? Anyone from any language can choose the Swiss number format, regardless of their language choice?

Comment: @JonW yes exactly

Comment: @JonW 'culture' is a perfectly valid (technical) term in this context. Quote: `The predefined cultures [...] provide information such as the language and calendar used in a country/region, and the text conventions` from [MSDN Create Custom Cultures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: @jfrej It might be *technically* accurate, but this is a web application for *users* to interact with, so users need to be able to understand what the labeling refers to. Maybe users understand the user of 'Culture' in this sense perfectly well, but I would be surprised if it didn't cause a lot of confusion.

Comment: @JonW oh, I agree. I was replying to `I've never heard of culture being used in this way before`. It is being used this way but only/mostly in technical contexts so not the best choice elsewhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**What you're looking for is called a '[Locale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale)' (a more technical term) or 'Region settings' (better to understand for users).**

As some countries and regions share the same format it might be a better approach to ask the user what looks familiar to them:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCFChm.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

If you need to stick to the UI you've shown maybe this is a solution:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLWhy8.png)</sup>

**In your example** the user is obviously already registered (as they have username and password). **Why would they want to select language/locale every time they log in?** I would expect this to be in something like 'account settings' and not required to select on every login.

Comment: This is right: 
"Why would they want to select language/locale every time they log in"
The selected Language and Culture is saved in a cookie.

Comment: But cookies can get lost :) Why not save it in the users' account since he apparently has one, and load the page with the format according to the users setting?

Answer (score 7):

You may simply follow the windows operating system way. This last field can be called **Date/Number Format** and it can be provided as a configurable item at user level.

[image]

Comment: I am considering it

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered automatic culture detection by geo-tagging? The less options user have, the less is the possibility to screw something up

Comment: Please provide an option *somewhere*, though, even if it's hidden within the user's account settings. There are few things more annoying than being incorrectly identified by geoip. Also, comments on the question mention the possibility of bilingual countries, which would not work well with geoip. And you also need to account for users traveling overseas.

Comment: There is a possibility to automatically detect the culture and and giving the user option to accept or change it. 

As I understood, we are talking about date and time formats, not about languages.